# Flutter integrate voice messages with Zegocloud SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, zegocloud

Below is my error code:

```
send message failed with code: 110018, message: file duration error
```

Below is my current code:
(Allow pickup file audio as mp3 from my local device then send using ZIMkit)

```
ZIMKit().pickFiles(type: FileType.any).then((files) => {
      ZIMKit().sendMediaMessage(
        toConversationID,
        ZIMConversationType.peer,
        files,
        onMessageSent: (p0) {
          return const Text('Loading...');
        },
      ).onError((error, stackTrace) => {
            debugPrint(error.toString()),
          })
    });
```

[Here is file mp3 audio info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPf7N.png)